# Showing $[A,(A^\dagger)^n]=n(A^\dagger)^{n-1}$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Given the operators $$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(x+\frac{d}{dx}\right)\text{    and     }
A^\dagger=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(x-\frac{d}{dx}\right)$$

and the commutator $[A,B]=AB-BA$ for Operators $A,B$,
I want to show that

$$[A,(A^\dagger)^n]=n(A^\dagger)^{n-1}$$

What Ive tried so far is using induction:

$$[A,(A^\dagger)^n]=[A,(A^\dagger)^{n-1}A^\dagger]=
A(A^\dagger)^{n-1}A^\dagger-(A^\dagger)^{n-1}A^\dagger A$$

Bot from here on I dont know where to go.
Therefore help is very much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, just recall the result

$$
[A, BC] = [A,B]C + B[A,C] \tag{1}
$$

So that

\begin{eqnarray}
[A, (A^\dagger)^n] &=& [A, (A^\dagger)(A^\dagger)^{n-1}] \\
&\stackrel{(1)}{=}& [A, A^\dagger](A^\dagger)^{n-1} + A^\dagger [A, (A^\dagger)^{n-1}] \\
&=& (A^\dagger)^{n-1} + A^\dagger\left\{(n-1)(A^\dagger)^{n-2} \right\} \\
&=& (A^\dagger)^{n-1} + (n-1)(A^\dagger)^{n-1} \\
&=& n(A^\dagger)^{n-1}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

This follows from the Leibniz rule. Ie.
$$ [A, (A^*)^n] = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} (A^*)^{j} [A, A^*] (A^*)^{n-1-j} $$
Then the result follows from the case $n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to show $[A, A^\dagger]=1$, which gives the identity $AA^\dagger = 1+ A^\dagger A$.

Calculating, we have \begin{align} [A, (A^\dagger)^n]&= A(A^\dagger)^n - (A^\dagger)^nA \\ &= (AA^\dagger)(A^\dagger)^{n-1} - (A^\dagger)^nA \\& =(1+A^\dagger A)(A^\dagger)^{n-1}- (A^\dagger)^nA \\&= (A^\dagger)^{n-1} + (A^\dagger)[A,(A^\dagger)^{n-1}]\end{align}
The result then follows by induction.